# Why virtual inheritance doesn't work in this case?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a code shown below. `XBase` and `XBar` are classes of `X` library, so I'm not able to change them.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// -- library stuff -- I can't change this
struct XBase {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct XBar : public XBase {
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "XBar::foo()" << endl;
    }
};
// --


// -- my stuff --
struct Base : public XBase {
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "Base::foo()" << endl;
    }
};

struct Bar : public virtual Base, public virtual XBar { // <-- that's ok, but doesn't let use XBase pointer to Bar instance
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "Bar::foo()" << endl;
    }
};
// --

int main() {
    Bar bar;
    bar.foo();
    static_cast<Base*>(&bar)->foo();
    static_cast<XBar*>(&bar)->foo();

    static_cast<XBase*>(&bar)->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The code isn't compiled because `Bar` definition isn't valid.

**1) Why compiler isn't able to find out that `Base` and `XBar` have the same parent and let me use virtual inheritance here?**

**2)** Is it possible to use virtual inheritance if, for example, `B` and `C` have common ancestor `A`, but they have different base classes?
It's like a [diamond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem#The_diamond_problem) but there is a another class between `C` and `A`.

**UPD:**
Second question the same as -- Why `B` and `C` have to be deriviatives of `A` explicitly?

---

It would be better to avoid multiple inheritance, and, I guess, it will be a workaround but questions still are.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to this:

```
  // -- library stuff -- 
struct XBase {
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct XBar : public XBase {
  virtual void foo() {
    cout << "XBar::foo()" << endl;
  }
};
// --


// -- my stuff --
struct Base : public virtual XBar {
  virtual void foo() {
    cout << "Base::foo()" << endl;
  }
};

struct Bar : public  Base { 
  virtual void foo() {
    cout << "Bar::foo()" << endl;
  }
};
// --
```

Comment: `I'm not able to change them.`

Comment: as they are in library?

Comment: yep it is in the library header files.

Comment: will this design help your cause https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1xNtnsgZBdpZk93NGdsRkNINkE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: yes, it will. Actually it was mentioned in the post that avoiding multiple inheritance will possibly help.

Comment: If that is the case you can test and verify your design.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `XBar` and `Base` do not use virtual inheritance from `XBase`.  If they did I think it would work.  But `XBar` and `Base` as defined each want their own individual `XBase`.